# Define a struct and create a list of related data items in one pass?

Tags: c++, macros, template-meta-programming

I'd like to implement a system whereby I can use a set of macros (or templates) to create a struct and some data in a single pass. It would be used something like this (the syntax isn't fixed, anything that works would be fine):

```
def_vert(MyVertex)
{
    element(float, 3, Position,     POSITION, 0);
    element(float, 3, Normal,       NORMAL, 0);
    element(float, 2, UVa,          TEXCOORD, 0);
    element(float, 2, UVb           TEXCOORD, 1);
    element(float, 4, DiffuseColor, COLOR, 0);
}
end_def()
```

And would output:

```
struct MyVertex
{
    float3 Position;
    float3 Normal;
    float2 UVa;
    float2 UVb;
    float4 DiffuseColor;
};
```

*and also*:

```
field_definition MyVertex_field_defs[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, float_type, 3 },
    { "NORMAL", 0, float_type, 3 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, float_type, 2 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 1, float_type, 2 },
    { "COLOR", 0, float_type, 4 }
};
```

I can't see a way to do this (create the 2 separate blocks of output) using macros or TMP - does anyone know if it's possible? I'm not able to use boost directly, but it would be useful to know if that would provide a solution.

One grim option is to use include files like this:

**MyVertex.h** contains the definition
**def_makestruct.h** contains macros to create the struct
**def_makefields.h** contains macros to create the fields

then:

```
#include "def_makestruct.h"
#include "MyVertex.h"
#include "def_makefields.h"
#include "MyVertex.h"
```

So I would at least only have to edit the definition in one place, but it would have to be in it's own file. Is there a better way?

Comment: why would you want that? you would end up writing more code then before.

Comment: @Axalo: I don't understand, sorry. I want to avoid having to edit the definition in more than one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called [X Macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

In the case you don't want to include any files or provide element/def_vert/end_vert definitions at every expansion site, you can pass them as extra parameters to MyVertexDef macro.

```
#define MyVertexDef(def_vert, element, end_def) \
def_vert(MyVertex) \
    element(float, 3, Position, POSITION, 0) \
    element(float, 3, Normal, NORMAL, 0) \
    element(float, 2, UVa, TEXCOORD, 0) \
    element(float, 2, UVb,           TEXCOORD, 1) \
    element(float, 4, DiffuseColor, COLOR, 0) \
end_def()

#define struct_def_vert(name) struct name {
#define struct_end_def() };
#define struct_element(type, size, name, meaning, index) type name; 

#define array_def_vert(name) field_definition name##_field_defs[] = {
#define array_end_def() };
#define array_element(type, size, name, meaning, index) {#name, index, type##_type, size},

#define GenerateStruct(T) T(struct_def_vert, struct_element, struct_end_def)
#define GenerateArray(T) T(array_def_vert, array_element, array_end_def)
...
//Where you want your struct MyVertex
GenerateStruct(MyVertexDef)
...
//Where you want MyVertex_field_defs
GenerateArray(MyVertexDef)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I used the subsequent tecnique in order to avoid to write two times the same string.

define a macro that will be used on a file as:

write only once the needed data in a file named data.cpp

```
mcr(NORMAL,3,Normal)
mcr(TEXCOORD,2,UVa)
mcr(TEXCOORD,2,UVb)
mcr(COLOR,4,DiffuseColor)
```

in another file write

```
#define mcr(a,b,c,etc) define_as_needed
struct MyVertex
{
#include "data.cpp"
}
#undef mcr

#define mcr(a,b,c,etc) define_as_needed
```

than redefinine the macro

```
#define mcr(a,b,c,etc) define_as_needed

field_definition MyVertex_field_defs[] =
{
#include "data.cpp"
};

#undef mcr
```

in my case I do the above redefinition 3 of 4 times depending on what needed changing the definition of the macro each time.

Adapt the code to your needs.
Especially for definitions of constants and of the associated string and data in structures it is very convenient.

Comment: Right, this is similar to the option at the end of the question. Can it be done without using includes though?

Comment: I learned that it can be done without includes in the way described by the previous answer !

Comment: you really shouldn't #include *.cpp files though

Comment: @axalo What you mean exactly ?

Comment: .cpp files will be compiled and header files will be included. You included a .cpp file.

Comment: It is true that i don't make a lot of difference between the two, I usually include everything. I will investigate it a little bit more.